# How to search for results only if everyone is tagged on mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a select with an inner join and a condition, get the nulls and the ones marked at 0, but when my inner join has 2 records for the same key it returns only 1 the marked at zero being that it has a marked with 1, A condition, bring only if all of the key is at 0, if you have at least 1 marked with 1 it does not bring anything;

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    TAB1
        LEFT JOIN
    TAB2 ON TAB1.id_tab2 = TAB2.id
WHERE
    (TAB2.ac = 0 OR TAB2.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding. Perhaps it would be more clear if you could provide a sample of the data in the two tables, what output you're expecting, and what output you're getting.

Comment: can you add sample data and expected output..